# Dynamic Text (string) in TextBox

Tags: c#, string

I have a form that defines how a future string will be constructed:

[image]

The user types in the top 4 boxes the corresponding numbers to which order they wish their string to be formatted. In the box below I want a string to be dynamically created to show an example of what they want.

Eg. If they type `1-2-4` (Relating to an index in a List) I want to show `110ME1C001A` (1 = `110`, 2 = `ME1`, 4 = `C`. The `001A` is relating to the "Sequence" and "Parallel" demonstrated at the top of the form).

If they select the separator checkbox, the string would become `110-ME1-C-001-A`

If they select the Reverse Sequence; `110-ME1-C-A-001`.

And then decide they want `2-4-3` without the separator and a normal sequence: `ME1CME2001A`. (You get the idea).

I have a *very* basic idea of how string parameters work, so I'm not too sure how to start. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to do this or what to search for to help me with this?

Comment: What is the relation between 1-2-4 and 110ME1C001A? How you decide that this string is converted only in that? Please put some code? Please tell us what you have tried?

Comment: It should be possible for sure but difficult to understand the logic of your example here. Can you be more explicit how it generates the serial?

Comment: @Nirav I'm not sure of your confusion, but to (hopefully) clarify: 1-2-4 would correspond to the list below, so `Area Code - Origin - Cable Type` or an example of that would be `110 - ME1 - C`. Then the sequence and parallel are required, so they would be added automatically; `001 - A`

Comment: @Nadeem_MK I really haven't tried anything properly because I really have no idea of how to start this. I had thought about using the parameters, but I think that's still too static. i.e. `"{0}{1}{2}, 110, ME1, ME2"` would only print `"110ME1ME2"` would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to populate an array to use as a parameter list, and create the string as follows. May not be perfect, but you should be able to adjust it to what you need:

```
// Create an array of the parameters, including the separator 
var parameters = new string[5];
parameters[0] = string.Empty;
parameters[1] = "area";
parameters[2] = "origin";
parameters[3] = "destination";
parameters[4] = "type";

// Will give: areaorigindestinationtype
var result1 = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}", parameters);

// Now change the separator:
parameters[0] = "-";
// Will give: area-origin-destination-type
var result2 = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}", parameters);

// Finally, reverse the last four parts:
Array.Reverse(parameters, 1, 4);
// Will give: type-destination-origin-area
var result3 = String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}", parameters);
```

If you have other stuff you want in your string too, you can just put it in there, like `sequence` and `parallel`, if these should always come last:

```
// Note the two added {0}'s to add more separators:
String.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}{4}{0}sequence{0}parallel", parameters);
```

Comment: Really sorry for the lack of information but this is really stepping the way I was looing for. Thanks so much!